# Skip update columns that were not passed in the source

Tags: pg-promise

Is there any syntax in column name's string or `helpers.sets` interface to skip columns for nonexisting properties in the data source?

Now, I need to create ColumnConfig as
`new helpers.Column({ name, skip: c => !c.exists })`
for every possible column.

It would be nice to have something like:

```
pgp.helpers.sets(values, SomeRepository.cs.update, skipNonExisting);
```

or at least:

```
pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['column1*', 'column2*']);
```

where * (or any other convinient symbol) is indicating that column is optional in the source and it's not throwing `"Property 'name' doesn't exist."`

Need this for `helpers.sets` (not for an `update` as I have some non-trivial update SQL).

As documentation says (http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.sets) when columns param in sets is not specified, properties of the data object are used.

That works fine until I need special formatting for some column, and then sets works only for defined columns in ColumnsSets if specified.

Comment: `That works fine until I need special formatting for some column, and then sets works only for defined columns in ColumnsSets if specified.` I'm not certain what the problem is here. Adding an example would help.

Answer (score 0):

In modern JavaScript you can abbreviate things easily, with a single line...

And so to turn a list of column names into a list of optional columns:

```
const cndCols = arr => arr.map(name => ({name, skip: c => !c.exists}));
```

Declaring [ColumnSet](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) object:

```
const cs = pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(cndCols(['column1', 'column2']));
```

It is not anymore complicated than the solution suggested in the question.

> Need this for helpers.sets (not for an update as I have some non-trivial update SQL).

For that you create and use two separate [ColumnSet](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) objects.

Comment: Ok, it's pretty the same as my 2nd suggestion. But 1st suggestion is the simplest:

pgp.helpers.sets(values, SomeRepository.cs.update, skipNonExisting);

No need to list all columns at all.

Ok, it is possible to retrieve keys from source and then filter columns set.

Comment: @TihomirMagdic The column name as string already supports `?name` for conditional columns, adding `*` for a different conditional check would create confusion.

Comment: Columns with prefix ? are ignored in SET so this it is not helpful in this case.

Comment: @TihomirMagdic I don't follow. You need to clarify that last statement.

Comment: @TihomirMagdic You misunderstood me before. I said that we already have a conditional symbol within the string format, and adding another conditional symbol for something else would create a confusion. Anyway, the solution I provided is all that you would need in your case.

Comment: Any suggestions without providing a list of all columns names at all?

Comment: @TihomirMagdic Why do you need a different solution? Is there a problem with this one? The class also can auto-enumerate properties of an object, to be used as column names, if that's what you are implying.

Comment: You misunderstood me before. With your solution, I need to list (and change the list on any table structure changes) all possible columns for updates. For some tables, it can be only a few columns but for bigger tables several dozens.

With pgp.helpers.sets(values, SomeRepository.cs.update, skipNonExisting) there no need at all to list all columns or filter any column.

I hope that clarifies my suggestion.

Comment: ColumnSet is a static structure, to work only with what you have specified. It does not work with any dynamic columns. And without specifying the columns, I'm not sure what kind of SQL you are planning to generate from a `set` operation, which needs specific columns. Anyhow, I only sense more confusion building up here, no point having this discussion in the comments. If you have another concern, or proposal, there's the [library's forum also](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues).